# How can I properly reword: "This particular "X" is not unique in this regard."

Tags: word-usage

Editing an essay, I recently found myself stuck trying to rewrite the sentence: "This particular journal publication is not unique in this regard."  It "sounds wrong" to use the word "this" twice in this manner.  Is there a simple fix?

Comment: It sounds worse out of context than it would following the previous sentence. I'd possibly change 'regard' to 'respect'; 'that' may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could say that "X holds no monopoly on (whatever this regard is a reference to).

It is shorter, doesn't rely on "is", and cuts down on indirect references, which are all good things in my mind.  I presume that X should be clear from the context, but I may be wrong.